# Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential (PHP)

Tags: php, google-people-api

I want to import Google contact in PHP but I am facing error after user Google sign in
Thank in advance

```
  $clientId = '******';
  $clientSecret = '*******';
  $google_redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/project/contact-list/';
  $scopes       = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly'];
    try {
        $googleOAuth2Handler =  new GoogleOAuth2Handler($clientId, $clientSecret, $scopes);
        $googleImportUrl = $googleOAuth2Handler->authUrl;
        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            $people = new GooglePeople($googleOAuth2Handler);
            // Retrieval all contacts
            foreach ($people->all() as $contact) {
                echo $contact->resourceName . ' - ';
                if ($contact->names) {
                    echo $contact->names[0]->displayName;
                }
                echo PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($e);
    }
```

```
Exception Object
(
    [message:protected] => {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "people.googleapis.com",
          "method": "google.people.v1.PeopleService.ListConnections"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use screenshots of errors; include the text of the error in the question itself. (this makes it searchable and easier to read)

Comment: Now you can help?